# Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file (pytorch model forward)

Tags: matlab, pytorch, mex, libtorch

When I call mex api from Matlab, I got an unexpected standard exception.

I exported 2 pytorch DNN models to 'A.pt' and 'B.pt' files.

And I implemented c++ functions that load models from the '.pt 'files and run models (forward).

The c++ implementation works fine, I can get proper results from the models.

I built the load & run forward function into '.dll' library,
and I implemented a mex api function can call them.

When I call the mex api in Matlab environment,
the 2 models are loaded normally, and the first model runs forward properly.

However, when run forward the 2nd model, I got the following exception.

---

Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file

What():The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.

Traceback of TorchScript (most recent call last):

RuntimeError: The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.

Traceback of TorchScript (most recent call last):

RuntimeError: error in LoadLibraryA

---

I have no clue why the c++ implementation works fine but the exception occurs when call it through mex api from Matlab.

Because the load & run forward functions are unchanged I expected the exactly same results.

It is more difficult to debug because there is no call-stack print.

Is there any way to get call-stack ?

Please give me any advice.

Thanks in advance.

-environment-------------------------------

c++ compiler : visual studio 2017 community

matlab : R2020a

libtorch : 1.6

pytorch : 1.5

python : 3.6

cuda : 10.2

---

Comment: LoadLibraryA error indicates that a DLL could not be found or not be loaded. MATLAB changes the path and other environment variables, which might make it so some library is not found. Or maybe it’s a library that MATLAB also uses, but it has an older/newer version.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Mr. Cris Luengo. I think you'are right. However I copied all libtorch dll files, opencv dll and my own dll & mexw64 into  my own folder( Matlab/Release).  And in the Matlab/matlab_call_structure_flow.m  file I added this folder' path using addpath('Release'), So I thought that all dlls are provided with known path.

Answer (score 1):

From Mr. Cris Luengo's comments, I solved this problem by copying all libtorch dlls into Matlab's own bin folder. There are several duplicated files but I overwrote them. I'm not sure it is safe or not, so may be backup of previous dlls is good choice. Thank you Mr. Cris Luengo.